# JavaFX VBox and HBox layouts

Tags: layout, javafx-2

I'm working on a `JavaFX` application which has a layout generated from an external data structure, composed of

- displaying components that know their own aspect ratios (height as a dependent of width)
- 2 types of structural components that

  - display all children with an equal width across their page, each child up as much vertical space as needed
  - display all children down the page using the full width and taking as much vertical space as needed

But I'm finding things aren't displaying as I expect. I've made a simplified case that demonstrates the problem.

The code is below, and the problem is that `v3` doesn't get displayed, and I can't for the life of me work out why. I guess there's some facet of `VBox`es and `HBox`es that I haven't understood.

I'd really appreciate any help or ideas. Thanks in advance!

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class Test extends Application {

    static Random rand = new Random();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Application.launch("something");
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage mainStage) throws Exception {
        testVBoxes(mainStage);
    }

    private void testVBoxes(Stage mainStage) {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        Scene one = new Scene(root, 800, 600, Color.WHITE);

        FixedAspectRatioH h1 = new FixedAspectRatioH();
        FixedAspectRatioH h2 = new FixedAspectRatioH();
        FixedAspectRatioH h3 = new FixedAspectRatioH();
        FixedAspectRatioV v1 = new FixedAspectRatioV();
        FixedAspectRatioV v2 = new FixedAspectRatioV();
        FixedAspectRatioV v3 = new FixedAspectRatioV();

        h1.prefWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty());

        h2.add(v2);

        v1.add(h3);
        v1.add(h2);

        h1.add(v1);
        h1.add(v3);

        root.getChildren().add(h1);

        mainStage.setScene(one);
        mainStage.show();
    }

    private class FixedAspectRatioV extends VBox {
        public FixedAspectRatioV() {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            r.setFill(Color.rgb(rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256),     rand.nextInt(256)));
            r.widthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
            r.heightProperty().bind(r.widthProperty().divide(3));
            getChildren().add(r);
        }

        public void add(Region n) {
            n.prefWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
            getChildren().add(n);
        }
    }

    private class FixedAspectRatioH extends HBox {
        public FixedAspectRatioH() {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            r.setFill(Color.rgb(rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256),     rand.nextInt(256)));
            r.widthProperty().bind(widthProperty().divide(4));
            r.heightProperty().bind(r.widthProperty());
            getChildren().add(r);
        }

        public void add(Region n) {
            HBox.setHgrow(n, Priority.ALWAYS);
            getChildren().add(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what is your idea of the app, but it seems you are having trouble with layouts. Try `root.requestLayout()` after the stage has been shown (after `mainStage.show()`). Or try to use `prefWidthProperty` for bindings instead of `widthProperty` of V|HBoxes.

Comment: Calling `root.requestLayout()` does fix the layout -- but why is this needed? It seems to me like a hack, so I'd like to know if there's a way to avoid the call. Using `predWidthProperty` instead of `widthProperty` results in nothing being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its 2 years but the solution  is you forgot

```
Node.setPrefSize(width,height);
```

and also add this to your constructor `Hbox.setFillHeight(true);`

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for finding & answering this. I have no way of checking that it's right, so I'll accept it unless someone else can say it doesn't work.