# How do I add items into tabs on JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, tabs, tableview

How do I add lets say a label inside the first tab of a TabPane. I'm new with java fx but swing is totally different. I'm not familiar with the terminology. Is pane a JPanel essentially? or is a scene?

Here's my class, I'm trying to add a Table inside my tabs but I can't get it to appear.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;


public class Viewer {

private Scene mainScene;
private MenuBar menubar;
private Menu menu;
private MenuItem menuItem, menuItem2, menuItem3;
private TableView table, table2;
private ScrollPane scroll;
private Pane npcPane, itemPane;

public Viewer() {

}

public Scene mainScene() {
    BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();
    BorderPane tabLayout = new BorderPane();
    Label label = new Label("Test");
    mainScene = new Scene(layout, 400, 600);

    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
    Tab tab = new Tab("Item");
    tab.setClosable(false);
    tab.setContent(tabLayout);
    tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);

    tabLayout.getChildren().add(label);

    layout.setCenter(tabPane);

    return mainScene;
}

private Node npcContent(){
    BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();
    npcPane = new Pane();

    TableColumn<NPC, Integer> idColumn = new TableColumn<>("ID:");
    idColumn.setMinWidth(100);
    idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));

    TableColumn<NPC, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name:");
    nameColumn.setMinWidth(250);
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

    table = new TableView<NPC>();
    table.setItems(getNpcs());
    table.getColumns().addAll(idColumn, nameColumn);

    scroll = new ScrollPane(table);
    layout.setCenter(scroll);
    return npcPane;
}

private Node itemContent() {
    itemPane = new Pane();

    TableColumn<Item, Integer> idColumn = new TableColumn<>("ID:");
    idColumn.setMinWidth(100);
    idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));

    TableColumn<Item, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name:");
    nameColumn.setMinWidth(250);
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

    table = new TableView<Item>();
    table.setItems(getItems());
    table.getColumns().addAll(idColumn, nameColumn);

    scroll = new ScrollPane(table);


    itemPane.getChildren().addAll(scroll);
    itemPane.setMinSize(500, 500);

    return itemPane;
}

public ObservableList<NPC> getNpcs() {
    ObservableList<NPC> npcs = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    ReadFile readFile = new ReadFile("./lists/npclist.txt");
    try {
        String[] npcList = readFile.openNPCFile();

        for(NPC npc : ReadFile.npcs) {
            if (npc != null) {
                npcs.add(new NPC(npc.getId(), npc.getName()));
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return npcs;
}

public ObservableList<Item> getItems() {
    ObservableList<Item> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    ReadFile readFile = new ReadFile("./lists/itemlist.txt");
    try {
        String[] itemList = readFile.openNPCFile();

        for(Item item : ReadFile.items) {
            if (item != null) {
                items.add(new Item(item.getId(), item.getName()));
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return items;
}

}
```

Comment: but does the Tabpane appear?

Comment: No I don't think so.

Comment: did it help you Sir? if so you can accept and upvote, also if you want to change the size of any node like pane,anchorpane or anything that extends region that use setPrefHeight or setPrefSize, you can ask if you have more questions

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question your `layout` is the parent `Node` of your `stage`

```
mainScene = new Scene(layout, 400, 600);
```

and your `tabPane` is next in your Node hierarchy which is your `layout` child, by default the `Borderpane` computes this range based on its content - or the size of its children if not explicitly set, you  **never** set the size of the `BorderPane` & `Tabpane` & `Label` you only set the size for your scene which your Stage will automatically use. so to solve your problem implement this method 
 [**`Region.setPrefSize(width,height);`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#setPrefSize-double-double-)
in every `Node` you have, so FX can know how to position your `Node` in its respective Parent

[related quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302961/javafx-vbox-and-hbox-layouts/31266982#31266982)

hope it helps

Comment: Ok thanks, one more question how would I change the size of a tableview? Do I change the size of a scene?

Comment: no sir change the size of the tableview itself, `TableView.setPrefHeight()` for the height and width is `TableView.setPrefWidth()` play with any node's size,changing the size of the scene might not automatically change the sizes of children @7Winds btw did it work? if so accept it

Answer (score 0):

Using `tabobj.setContent(node);` You Can Add Any Control or Layout into the tab.